# Why is the Twitter bot tweeting Meta posts (again)?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, per-site-meta, twitter, regression

I noticed that the [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackMusic) for [Music: Practice & Theory SE](https://music.stackexchange.com/) is tweeting posts from the site's Meta, for example:

- Jun 23: [How should we respond to questions whose answer depends on the genre?](https://twitter.com/StackMusic/status/1275398233620123648?s=20)
- Apr 6: [Should the Help Center be updated?](https://twitter.com/StackMusic/status/1246950913564184576?s=20)
- Feb 15: [Edition of a question: how to contact editor?](https://twitter.com/StackMusic/status/1228695578474942464?s=20)

and [several others](https://twitter.com/search?q=%40StackMusic%20music.meta.stackexchange.com&src=typed_query).

There have been many questions in the past about whether the Twitter bot should be tweeting Meta posts at all. The [most recent one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319364/313042) that I could find is tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) for no longer tweeting Meta posts, but all the tweets that I have listed above are very recent—tweeted long after the [status-completed] tag was applied.

Is this a bug? If it is, can it be fixed? I don't know whether it is only Music's Twitter account that is tweeting Meta posts. I am not aware of any simple way to search for other examples, I just happened to stumble across this situation.

Comment: It's not just Music Meta, I found a recent post from [Academia Meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5225/timeline#history_dce8250c-d411-4d00-9092-155867dbc3c6) that was tweeted.

Comment: This can be desirable in some cases. As an example, the Travel photo competitions on its meta get tweeted, and that's nice as it exposes the competition to more people. Sites should be able to opt in to having meta questions tweeted if they wish.

Answer (score 4):

With the recent changes to Twitter's API access policy, we have opted to shut down the automatic Twitter bots. See [Are the various site Tweetbots affected by the upcoming Twitter API changes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386451/are-the-various-site-tweetbots-affected-by-the-upcoming-twitter-api-changes) for more info.

For what it's worth, while removing the code that made it all go, I did find out that we were intentionally tweeting meta questions ~25% of the time so long as they were no more than 30 days old and met a handful of other criteria depending on whether they were [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) posts or had one of the other required tags. The idea was to pick out questions that were of likely interest to that site's community, and the [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319364/why-do-site-meta-questions-get-posted-on-twitter) mentioned in this question had to do with meta sites tweeting questions as if they were a main site rather than following those criteria.

Answer (score -3):

Checking the Stack Exchange [Life / Arts](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#lifearts-traffic) list we see that [Music Practice & Theory's Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackMusic) is listed on the Stack Exchange [Network site](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questions).

A list of Twitter accounts is maintained at the question: ["Why is it so difficult to find the twitter account for a Stack Exchange site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308669/282094).

See also: ["How does the twitter bot work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183410/282094).

Music's latest Tweet was less than an hour ago, so it's probably intentional that they are using it to promote their site; they have no recent meta posts about it on their site.

Comment: Check the age on the post. The music post was a while back but it's occured again

Comment: The question asked is: "Is this a bug? If it is, can it be fixed? I don't know whether it is only Music's Twitter account that is tweeting Meta posts. I am not aware of any simple way to search for other examples, ...", I have answered it.

Comment: If you're not sure if how to search for examples, maybe it isn't an answer? I follow SU on Twitter so I know it happens there too but this is very much something that needs staff attention to fix.